# Node.js concurrent API GETs, return as soon as one responses

Tags: node.js, axios, get, request

I have a list of APIs I want to call GET simultaneously on all of them and return as soon as one API finishes the request with a response code of 200.

I tried using a for-loop and break, but that doesn't seem to work. It would always use the first API

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const listOfApi = ['https://example.com/api/instanceOne', 'https://example.com/api/instanceTwo'];

let response;
for (const api of listOfApi) {
    try {
        response = await axios.get(api, {
            data: {
                url: 'https://example.com/',
            },
        });
        break;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error occurred: ${error.message}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.race()` to see which of an array of promises finishes first while running all the requests in parallel in flight at the same time:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const listOfApi = ['https://example.com/api/instanceOne', 'https://example.com/api/instanceTwo'];

Promise.any(listOfApi.map(api => {
    return axios.get(api, {data: {url: 'https://example.com/'}}).then(response => {
        // skip any responses without a status of 200
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error(`Response status ${response.status}`, {cause: response});
        }
        return response;
    });
})).then(result => {
    // first result available here
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note, this uses `Promise.any()` which finds the first promise that resolves successfully (skipping promises that reject).  You can also use `Promise.race()` if you want the first promise that resolves or rejects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention one more thing, I would like to have the first response with status code 200 returned, could you please show me how that's done? Cheers

Comment: @Hackel - The original code would already filter for responses that were 2xx because that is the default for `axios()`.  If you want 200 only, I've modified my answer to show that.

Comment: @CherryDT - Corrected.  That happened in an edit related to something else the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831556/1871033) is good, but I want to expand on it a bit and show how it would look with `async`/`await`, because that's what you are already using.

As mentioned, you can use `Promise.any` (or `Promise.race`). Both take an array of promises as argument. `Promise.any` will yield the result of the first promise that resolves successfully, while `Promise.race` will simply wait for the first promise that finishes (regardless of whether it was fulfilled or rejected) and yield its result.

To keep your code in the style of `async`/`await` as it originally was, you can `map` the array using an `async` callback function, which will effectively return a promise. This way, you don't have to "branch off into `.then` territory" and can keep the code more readable and easier to expand with conditions, etc.

This way, the code can look as follows:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const listOfApi = ['https://example.com/api/instanceOne', 'https://example.com/api/instanceTwo'];

try {
    const firstResponse = await Promise.any(listOfApi.map(async api => {
        const response = await axios.get(api, {
            data: {
                url: 'https://example.com/',
            },
        });
        
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error(`Response status ${response.status}`, {cause: response});
        }
        
        return response;
    }));
    
    // DO SOMETHING WITH firstResponse HERE
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occured:', error);
}
```

<sub>Side note: I changed your `console.error` slightly. Logging only `error.message` is a common mistake that hinders you from effective debugging later on, because it will lack a lot of important information because it prints only the message and not the error stack, the error name or any additional properties the error may have. Using `.stack` and not `.message` will already be better as it includes name and stack then, but what's best is to supply the error as separate argument to `console.error` so that `inspect` gets called on it and it can print the whole error object, with stack and any additional properties you may be interested in. This is very valuable when you encounter an error in production that is not so easy to reproduce.</sub>